# How to use a method of a library Android that I created?

Tags: android, class, hierarchy

I created a library Android: AndroidLib. 
I have marked this like as "isLibrary" in the settings.
I imported this in my project and I added AndroidLib in BuildPath.
Now, I must invoke the method 
`public void inviaDati(String,String,String,String,String)`
from AndroidLib in my new project.

How can I do?

I should do it statically, not an object. 
What's the syntax?

Comment: is the method declared sa public?

Comment: yes, but i tried to change in static and equally i don't know I do not know how to invoke it. I tried with "inviaDati(String,..)" and with AndroidLib.inviaDati(String,..) but in both cases the method is not recognized.

Comment: If the class declaring inviaDati() is the public class A {}, you need to 1. instantiate the A class with the new operator and trough the A object you can call the inviaDati() method